# Load Flutter plugin at runtime

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, module

my question is, is there a way to load a Flutter Plugin (or module) from runtime. So in the end I can download a single part of the app and then I can run it directly from the code. This plugin returns a widget, which the original App can display. For example: you have an app for editing documents, and in this app you can download plugins to edit MSWord files.

Thanks!